# Scala return type

Tags: scala

I have this as a return type in Scala

```
 Map[String, Seq[Map[String, Seq[MyClass]]]]
```

I have to use this in multiple places in my code, is there a way to assign this to a constant of sorts and use the constant instead of explicitly stating it?

Comment: You should also note that it's not ALWAYS necessary to declare your return types if the compiler can figure out what you're doing. But looking at how complicated that type is, @drexin's answer is probably the best way to go.

Comment: True although for a non-obvious type, it's best to declare the return type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can define a type alias with `type Foo = Map[...]`.

Comment: but note that this have to be defined inside class or object

Comment: om-nom-nom it can be defined in the package object as well